# Instancing an object and calling a method in one line?

Tags: php, oop

php 5.3

Is there a way to do this (viable in java for example)

```
(new MyClass())->myMethod();
```

i am receving: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in D.. on line 7`

## Add

I really need that RFC to be implemented in the next PHP version!

http://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call

Is there a way we can subscribe to it so it can get more attention?

Comment: one **line**? `$x = new MyClass(); $x->myMethod();`  or did you mean one **statement**? :D

Comment: if your declartion class's method is static (Factory pattern) then you can do `MyClass::myMethod();` http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php

Comment: There is no 'Factory' pattern, it is either Factory Method or Abstract Factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not possible. There is a RFC for that

http://wiki.php.net/rfc/instance-method-call

But no one knows, when this will come to the userland.

Jacob mentioned the static method. There are other more or less useful methods to achieve the same

```
function instanciate($className, $arg1 = null) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args);
    $c = new ReflectionClass($className);
    return $c->newInstanceArgs($c);
}
instanciate('Classname', 1, 2, 3)->doSomething();
```

However, I prefer the temporary variable (like in the question).

Update:
I can swear there where an example for the temporary variable stuff in the question in the past. However, I meant this

```
$x = new Class;
$x->method();
```

where `$x` is the temporary variable.

Comment: Interesting, would be a nice feature to have.

Comment: The downside to functions like that is IDE's won't be able to help you much with code completion.

Comment: the site is back up.. but how to apply that patch?

Comment: @yes123: You really want to patch something from an "in discussion" rfc into the php source, compile it yourself, and thats just for saving one line?! Oo

Comment: @yes123: I didnt patch php myself before, but I had a look at the patchfile and it seems, that this is a common file format for use with the `patch` tool. However, I dont know, whats going on right now, but really: Nobody "really needs" to save just one line ;)

Answer (score 3):

That is not valid syntax. A handy way to achieve what you want is to use a static method to create the object.

In your MyClass:

```
public static function create() {
    return new MyClass();
}
```

Then you can use:

```
MyClass::create()->myMethod();
```

However it is extra code that you have to maintain, if for example the constructor is changed or the class is extended. So you need to weigh up the benefits.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
function chain_statements($statement1, $statement2) { return $statement2; }

class TClass { public Method() { ...; return $this; } }

$b = chain_statements($a = new TClass(), $a->Method());
```

... or more generalized:

```
function chain_statements(array $statements) { return end($statements); }
```

For example:

```
function chain_statements($statement1, $statement2) { return $statement2; }
function chain_statements2(array $statements) { return end($statements); }
class TClass
{
    public $a = 0;
    public function Method1() { $this->a = $this->a + 1; return $this; }
    public function Method2() { $this->a = $this->a + 2; return $this; }
}
$b = chain_statements($c = new TClass(), $c->Method1()); echo($b->a);
$b = chain_statements2(array($c = new TClass(), $c->Method1(), $c->Method2())); echo($b->a);
```

... or even better:

```
function call_method($object) { return $object; }
$b = call_method(new TClass())->Method2(); echo($b->a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not as such. In PHP `new` is not an expression, but a language construct. The common workaround is to provide a static instantiation method for `MyClass::get()->...` use.

A more concise alternative is a hybrid factory function:

```
function MyClass() { return new MyClass; }
class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

Which then simplifies the instantiation to `MyClass()->doSomething();`

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in one statement if you really wanted to. Use eval() ;p

But you probably shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem a while ago but I found this simple solution which is pretty readable too. I like the fact it uses only the standard PHP functions. There's no need to create any utility functions of your own.

```
    call_user_func(
      array(new ClassToInstance(), 'MethodName'),
      'Method arguments', 'go here'
    );
```

You can also use `call_user_func_array` to pass the arguments as an array.

```
    call_user_func_array(
      array(new ClassToInstance(), 'MethodName'),
      array('Method arguments', 'go here')
    );
```